# Find the difference of two pronic numbers whose sum is 240.

Tags: number-theory, problem-solving

How do I do this without Excel/brute force, and how do I explain this to an 11 year old please? There's apparently supposed to be a trick to this because it's in a standardised exam.

Well I noticed that the difference between two consecutive numbers in the sequence of [pronic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronic_number) is an element of $\{4,6,8,10,12,...\}$.

Answer: I guess the pronic numbers are 30 and 210 and hence the difference is 180.

See here for a [long solution](https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Sequences-and-series/Sequences-and-series.faq.question.1006021.html). I lost my notes, but I think I can use quadratic formula here (or I'm confusing this with another question), but the 11 year old doesn't know quadratic. I think curriculum varies a lot from where she is as opposed to from where I am.

Comment: A [pronic number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronic_number) is a number in the form $n(n+1)$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @BCLC This problem is exactly equivalent to finding two squares that sum to $962$.  This could be solved immediately upon noting that $962 = 26\cdot 37 = (5^2+1^2)(6^2+1^2)$, but it seems unlikely that a child who is unfamiliar with quadratics would have studied the Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity... A well-chosen brute force still seems like the best way here.

Answer (score 2):

The pronic numbers are twice the triangular numbers $T_n$, so we'd be looking for two triangular numbers that sum to $120$.

I know the first few triangular numbers so $T_{10}=55$ and $T_{11}=66$ don't work; the easiest way to go from there is "up", so:
$T_{12}=78, \quad 120-78=42 \quad \times$
$T_{13}=91, \quad 120-91=29 \quad \times$
$T_{14}=105, \quad 120-105=15=T_5 \quad \checkmark $
$T_{15}=120, \quad 120-120=0=T_0 \quad ?$

And OK we can probably ignore that last one, but it also demonstrates there is no need to go further.

Then $T_{14}+T_5=120$ can be translated back into pronic numbers for the result.

Comment: Incidentally, the simple geometric proof that the pronic numbers are twice the triangular numbers might be an interesting result for an 11-year-old.

Comment: Thanks Joffan! ^-^ actually we can ignore the last since 0 is not a pronic number?

Comment: Joffan, any idea how to do this analytically? Not sure of term but not with brute force. But like let p1 and p2 be pronic. Then there exist a(a+1), b(b+1) s.t. etc

Comment: @BCLC tricky; sometimes you just have to check cases. You could probably reduce the cases more (if we were looking at a big number) with some checks on modulo values eg. 2,5

Answer (score 1):

if $a(a+1)+b(b+1)=240$, then must one of them less than $120$ or equal $120$. we can let $a < b$. as $11 \cdot 12 > 120 > 10 \cdot 11$, let us try $A$ less than $10 \cdot 11$, B great than $11 \cdot 12$, here $A=a(a+1), B=b(b+1)$.

the minimum $A$ is $A = 1 \cdot 2$, if $A=1 \cdot 2$, $B$ is the maximum, but if $B = 15 \cdot 16$, we have $A+B=242>240$, so $B < 15 \cdot 16$, the maximum $B$ is $14 \cdot 15$.

so we have $11 \cdot 12 \le B \le 14 \cdot 15$
when $A = 10 \cdot 11$, then if $B = 11 \cdot 12, 12 \cdot 13, 13 \cdot 14, 14 \cdot 15$, $A+B \neq 240$. note, when check $A+B \neq 240$, we can try the last digit of $A+B$ $=$ or $\neq$ zero, the same check below.

when $A=9 \cdot 10$, then check $B = 11 \cdot 12, 12 \cdot 13, 13 \cdot 14, 14 \cdot 15$ by last digit, only need check $B=14 \cdot 15$, but $A+B = 9 \cdot 10+14 \cdot 15 \neq 240$, no solution.

when $A=8 \cdot 9$, then check $B = 11 \cdot 12, 12 \cdot 13, 13 \cdot 14, 14 \cdot 15$ by last digit, no solution.

when $A=7 \cdot 8$, then check $B = 11 \cdot 12, 12 \cdot 13, 13 \cdot 14, 14 \cdot 15$ by last digit, no solution.

when $A = 6 \cdot 7$, then check $B = 11 \cdot 12, 12 \cdot 13, 13 \cdot 14, 14 \cdot 15$ by last digit, no solution.

when $A = 5 \cdot 6$, then we have your solution.

Comment: Thanks xunitc. Is there a way to do this analytically? Not sure of term but I mean not brute force